# Check if login failed

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, url, powershell-4.0

I have the following code, which logs into a site that I use frequently:

```
param(
      [string]$interval
)
function Refresh-WebPages {
        "Neptun refresh every $interval seconds."
        "press any key to exit."
        $shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
        do {
            Start-Sleep -Seconds $interval
            'Refreshing'
            $shell.Windows() | 
                Where-Object { $_.Document.url } | 
                ForEach-Object { $_.Refresh() }
        } until ( [System.Console]::KeyAvailable )
        [System.Console]::ReadKey($true) | Out-Null
    }
$username = "asd";
$SecureString = Read-Host "password" -AsSecureString;
$BSTR = 
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($SecureString);
$PlainPassword = 
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
$IE=new-object -com internetexplorer.application;
$IE.navigate2("https://hallgato.neptun.elte.hu/login.aspx");
$IE.visible=$true;
While ($IE.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500}
$IE.Document.getElementById('user').value = "$username";
$IE.Document.getElementById('pwd').value = "$PlainPassword";
($IE.document.getElementById('btnSubmit') |select -first 1).click();
Refresh-WebPages -interval
```

I want to check if the login have failed or succeeded. Can I check if the URL is different somehow?

Comment: That is different for each website. There might be a cookie you can check. Or maybe a header. Sometimes you can only check it through the DOM by looking for an element that is only visible to authenticated users.

Comment: A redirect after successful login is quite common. But there's no way for us to know that without creating an account.

Comment: @Raziel Thats a very good idea thanks!